# How do I test for a second form name if the first form name comes back undefined?

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to be able to test if theForm is defined, meaning it found a form with the name 'data'
How do we do that?

Then if it is not found I can test for the other form name and set the action on that named form.

```
function edit_OnClick() {
    var theForm = window.document.forms['data'];

    theForm.action = "checkout.asp";
    theForm.submit();

    return false;
}
```

Is it ok to post follow ups at stackoverflow?

This is what I came up with using your advice, but it is not switching like I planned.

```
    function edit_OnClick() {
        var theForm = window.document.forms['data'];
        if ( typeof ( theForm !== "undefined" )) {
            theForm.action = "checkout.asp";
            theForm.submit();

            return false;
        }else {
        var theForm = window.document.forms['form_bml'];
            theForm.action = "checkout.asp";
            theForm.submit();

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
var theForm = document.forms['data'];

if (theForm) {
  // do stuff
} else {
  theForm = document.forms['form_bml'];
  if (theForm) {
    // do other stuff
  }
}
```

If the actions for both are the same, then:

```
var theForm = document.forms['data'] || document.forms['form_bml'];
if (theForm) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( theForm ) { .. }
```

should be enough. If you want to be on the safe side you could go for

```
if ( typeof ( theForm ) !== "undefined" ) { ... }
```

Comment: Second statement is always `true` (it should be `"undefined"`)!

Comment: `typeof` is an operator, not a function, so there is no need for a grouping operator around the expression (though it's safe to do so).